# How to get Functor string in Prolog using pyswip

Tags: python, swi-prolog

I develop python app which connect to Prolog via pyswip.

The following is an example of Prolog part that I executed.

```
init( Board) :-
  Board = b(n,x,n,x,n,x,n,x,x,n,x,n,x,n,x,n,n,x,n,x,n,x,n,x,e,n,e,n,e,n,e,n,n,e,n,e,n,e,n,e,o,n,o,n,o,n,o,n,n,o,n,o,n,o,n,o,o,n,o,n,o,n,o,n).
```

When executing the following code

```
soln = list(self.prolog.query("init(B)"))
print(soln[0])
```

The soln[0] is

```
<'B': 'Functor6905740'>
```

How can I get b(n,x,n,x,...) instead of Functor reference?

Ps. I use all 64 bit: Python 2.7, SWI-Prolog, pyswip, Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution.
I import Functor, Variable, Query

```
from pyswip import Prolog, Functor, Variable, Query
```

To get the functor value, I use

```
init = Functor("init", 1)
B = Variable()
soln = Query(init(B))

while soln.nextSolution():
   b64 = B.get_value()
self.Board_pl = "b("
for i in range (0, 64):
    self.Board_pl += (str(b64.args[i]) + ",")
self.Board_pl += (str(b64.args[63]) + ")")
print(Board)
```

Then, the program will print

```
b(n,x,n,x,n,x,n,x,x,n,x,n,x,n,x,n,n,x,n,x,n,x,n,x,e,n,e,n,e,n,e,n,n,e,n,e,n,e,n,e,o,n,o,n,o,n,o,n,n,o,n,o,n,o,n,o,o,n,o,n,o,n,o,n)
```